# Windows Azure WebRole stuck in a deployment loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, azure

I've been struggling with this one for a couple of days now. My current Windows Azure WebRole is stuck in a loop where the status keeps changing between Initializing, Busy, Stopping and Stopped.

It never goes live, and I can can never see the website as a result. The WebRole is an "out of the box" MVC 2 application with Copy Local set to true on the Mvc dll and I haven't even tried hooking up a  storage or WorkerRole yet, and there is nothing really happening inside the Start method that I can see would crash.

I've really tried going back to basics to ensure nothing can complicate the process and the website launches without a problem on the Dev Fabric and yes it looks just like the standard "Home", "About" MVC app - just can't get it running in the cloud!

Funny thing is, a few days ago, this exact package *worked* on the staging area in the cloud, and I could even see it in the browser - but could never get it swapped over to production, so I deleted everything and started from scratch, and now I can't even get it running on staging...

Does anyone have any ideas on what I could do to diagnose this problem myself because since logging this problem on the forums 2 days ago, there has been no improvement or feedback.

Any help appreciated,
Regards,
Rob G

Comment: Did you allow Full Trust in your config?

Comment: Yes - I think I may have narrowed the problem down to diagnostics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there are a number of things that can cause this to happen. A full thread on the Microsoft forums goes through most of them and details my adventures in the arena.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazure/thread/1482c1af-16e3-46ca-846e-14f511c35750

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks. I was having the same problem - turns out the webrole.cs file wasn't loaded in the project for some reason.

Comment: Hi Roberto, did you follow any steps for debugging the problem? It will be great to know.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best starting point is enabling remote desktop on all role instances.
Saves a lot of heart ache wondering why the heck isn't the diagnostics aren't logging anything.

By remoting in you can eye ball the event logs and find lots of reasons for azure unhappness